# stuck at 92% "Launching: starting virtual machine" on eclipse java program

Tags: java, eclipse

very often when I try to compile and run a java program on eclipse it gets stuck at 92 percent and when I click on the bottom right corner it says "Launching: Starting virtual machine" so I close eclipse and when I reopen the program it works once but then when I try to launch it a second time I get the same problem, I'm using the windows 10 technical preview so it could be a problem with that and not eclipse. but I'm not sure can somebody please help.

Comment: More detail *might* be useful.  Is this an issue with one set of code or multiple projects; if singular, then can we see the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to increase your heap size:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse

Comment: thanks I think that worked it might just be a coincidence but I'm not getting the problem anymore